# Gerar PDF com Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Olá, na minha aplicação os relatórios são gerados em Html, gostaria de saber uma forma de gerar esses relatórios Html em PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu estou usando o MvcRazorToPdf
Link: https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf

Conforme sugerido neste link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/b7eceb48-884d-47d6-afec-45c3f1dc5d18/gerar-pdf-com-aspnet-mvc?forum=mvcpt

Answer (score 3):

O RazorPDF é uma boa alternativa, mas é incompatível com o iTextSharp versão 5 ou superior. Pensando nisso, [desenvolvi o RazorPDF2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2/).

[Aqui tem alguns exemplos de uso](https://github.com/DesignLiquido/RazorPDF2/blob/master/RazorPDFExample/Controllers/PdfSampleController.cs). Basicamente, defina sua *View* normalmente, mas use o `PdfActionResult` ou `PdfResult` para devolver o resultado. `PdfActionResult` trabalha com HTML normal. `PdfResult` trabalha com a sintaxe de marcação do iTextSharp até a versão 4.

Há, ainda, [o Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa), mas que não funciona na Azure.

Comment: O RazorPDF2 faz paginação ? tem como colocar imagem no cabeçalho ?

Comment: Não. Você teria que trabalhar diretamente com o iTextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

Quanto trabalhamos com desenvolvimento .NET (apesar que a maioria hoje tem isso) possui um repositório de pacotes que é chamado no mundo .NET [NUGET](https://www.nuget.org/).

Lá tem vários, eu recomendaria esse: [RazorPDF for MVC - Generate PDFs with... 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF/) e tem o tutorial nesse link: [RazorPDF](http://nyveldt.com/blog/page/razorpdf). Só lembrando que ele gera a partir de uma View um PDF!

Se quiser buscar outro pacote clique nesse [link de pesquisa](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=pdf).