# Criação de relatórios em C#!

Tags: c#, .net, relatório

Olá, estou procurando uma biblioteca/ferramenta que permite criar relatórios em c#.
Existe o Fast Report e o Crystal Reports mas ambos são pagos...
Queria algo Open Source/Gratuito e não precisa ter muito recursos.
Alguma dica?

Comment: você edtá dizendo criar arquivos de LOG?

Comment: Conheço grátis somente o report viewer do próprio visual studio http://www.macoratti.net/17/02/rpv_vs17.htm Agora tirando ele você pode encontrar geradores mas na linha de código iTextSharp por exemplo. Bom é isso basicamente. https://github.com/itext/itextsharp

Comment: Da uma olhada nesta [aplicação e biblioteca](https://github.com/majorsilence/My-FyiReporting). Eu já utilizei ela em um projeto meu.

Comment: usei recentemente o [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa), ele gera um PDF a partir da sua `View`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Gerar PDF com Asp.Net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91447/gerar-pdf-com-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Se for pra SQL Server tem o Sql Server Data Tools da Microsoft. Você gera o relatório na ferramenta depois integra os rdls na sua aplicação.